# When I scan in an array it changes another array?

Tags: c, arrays

```
int main()
{

char word[]="elephant";
char display[]="********";
int size;
int chance=10;
char choice[1]="a";
int i=0;
int indic=0;
char choice_1;


size=strlen(word);


printf("Would you like to guess the word [w] or guess a letter [l]:");
scanf("%c", &choice_1);

while(chance>0)
{


i=0;

if(choice_1=='w')
{

printf("Enter the word:");
scanf(" %s", choice);

    if(strlen(choice)!=size)
    {

    printf("Enter a word with the correct number of letters\n");

    }

    if(strlen(choice)==size)

    {

        while(i<size)
        {

        if(choice[i]==word[i])
        {

        indic++;   

        }

        i++;

        }



    if(indic==size)
    {
        printf("You have guessed the word!\n");
        break;
    }

    if(indic!=size)
    {
        printf("You have incorrectly guessed the word\n");
        chance=chance-1;
    }

    }

}

i=0;

if(choice_1=='l')
{

printf("Enter a letter:");
scanf(" %s", choice);

i=0;
indic=0;

    while(i<=size)
    {

    if(choice[0]==word[i])
    {

    display[i]=word[i];
    indic=1;

    }

    i++;

    }

i=0;

if(indic==0)
{

printf("BAD CHOICE!\n");
chance=chance-1;

    while(i<=size)
    {

        if(i==size)
        {
        printf("%c\n", display[i]);
        }

    printf("%c", display[i]);
    i++;

    }

}

if(indic==1)
{

printf("GOOD CHOICE!\n");

    while(i<=size)
    {

        if(i==size)
        {
        printf("%c\n", display[i]);
        }

    printf("%c", display[i]);
    i++;

    }

}

}



printf("You have %d chances left\n", chance);

printf("Would you like to guess the word [w] or guess a letter [l]:");
scanf(" %c", &choice_1);

}

return 0;

}
```

I'm trying to build a hangman programme for College, I only started programming this year. But I'm running into this problem. When I put an input into the array "**choice[]**" it also changes the array "**display[]**" for some reason. For example if I put in '*w*' for "**choice_1**" and '*elephank*' for " **choice[]**" (It should be elephant) the array "**display[]**" changes to "*lephank*". Why does it do this? I don't even use the display array in that loop to check if the word is right. I know this is a big block of code but since I don't know what's going on
I didn't know what else to do. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Read a C book! You confuse characters and character arrays and C-strings. And enable compiler warnings and pay heed to them. Your compiler wants to yell at you.

Comment: `char choice[1]="a";` can not hold your guessed string. It is a single char `a` with no terminator. You enter a string into a one-byte allocation, and it corrupts other variables.

Comment: Here u see Olaf instead of giving answers to @Kevin u just say he deosn't know nothing about cahr arrays and C-strings

Comment: I remember I read char arrays and pointers 10 times to master them

Comment: Thanks for the help guys I just changed it choice[strlen(word)] and it was fine.

Comment: Make that `choice[strlen(word)+1]` because `scanf` will add a string terminator.

Answer (score 0):

> I put in 'w' for "choice_1" and 'elephank' for " choice[]"

That's your problem. *choice* is a *char* ("array" of size 1), so you can only store one single character. Every further character is stored next to *choice* where the memory is reserved for *display*.